# Is there a Qt Jambi fork?

Tags: java, open-source, fork, qt-jambi

In March or April 2009 Qt Jambi was made open source and then the commercial project was  kicked. I'd really like to use Qt Jambi but can't do that if the code isn't maintained any longer.

Is there a fork of Qt Jambi, either commercial or open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the commit log, and the latest release, it seems Jambi itself is still under active development and is available under either LGPL or commercial licences. [See here for downloads.](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads#jambi) For reference, 4.5.0 was the first open source version.

Comment: Ah cool. I'll have a look at it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Qt Jambi 4.5.x series is maintained officially until May 2010. There is a community port to Qt 4.6 located here:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-jambi/community-port-to-4_6

Currently the Qt Jambi Interest mailing list is used for communication within the community.